# How to make Collection View cell more than one column?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[Here the output of the code but I want to make it into 2 column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3who.png)

I want to make a collection view with more than 1 column but this code just shows one column. Can anyone help me how to fixed it??? Thank You....

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Here the array

```
    var collectionArray : [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

    
    let labelnamee = [("Long Sleeve Abstract Print Top"), ("Logo Graphic Print Top"), ("Material Study T-Shirt"), ("Mission Statement Print T-Shirt"), ("Printed Logo T-Shirt"), ("Tie-Dye Print T-Shirt")]
    
    let labelpricee = [("RM 1021"), ("RM 860"), ("RM 750"), ("RM 750") , ("RM 670"), ("RM 760")]
    
    let imagee = [UIImage(named: "abstractprint"),
                   UIImage(named: "longsleeve"),UIImage(named: "studymaterial"),UIImage(named: "mission"), UIImage(named: "white"), UIImage(named: "tiedye")]
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labelnamee.count
    }
```

for the collection cell  border

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let cellIndex = indexPath.item
        cell.imageView.image = imagee[cellIndex]
        cell.labelname.text = labelnamee[cellIndex]
        cell.labelprice.text = labelpricee[cellIndex]
        
        cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
        
        return cell
    }

}
```

Here the code for the layout. I think I made mistake in the height or weight..

```
extension SearchViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let bounds = collectionView.bounds
        let heigtVal = self.view.frame.height
        let widthVal = self.view.frame.width
        let cellsize = (heigtVal < widthVal) ? bounds.height/2: bounds.width/2

        
        
        return CGSize(width: cellsize - 10, height: cellsize - 10)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }
}
```

Comment: are you placing your UI elements in a stackView in the collectionViewCell? Also, is there any width constraint applied on imageView?

Comment: no, I'm not using stack in the collection view cell and also I already set the same width for the image view to the cell, but it still show 1 column @VikramParimi

Comment: I have tried your exact code and was able to achieve two columns by providing the right width

Comment: what is the right width? how to set that? @VikramParimi

Comment: I have set the equal width, equal height and also the aspect ratio.. @VikramParimi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the width of the cell or the contents of the cells is such that the collectionView cannot accommodate be able to see them within the visible portion of the screen, the collection view automatically places next to them. You have to scroll your collecctionView to see your next column.

If you want to see two columns within the visible screen portion, pls follow the steps:

Firstly place all your views inside a `StackView` and align them vertically.

[image]

Then set the right `width` & `height` constraints to your imageView to maintain the aspect ratio for your requirements. I have set like below just to demonstrate:

[image]

Along with the above constraints, I have also set the cell size to automatic in Storyboard itself rather than doing programmatically. Removed `sizeForItemAt indexPath` from code

:[image]

Finally, after following all the above steps the output looked like this

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by heightForItemAtIndexpath? @VikramParimi

Comment: sizeForItemAt indexPath